# Display employee name who were hired on Sunday of October Month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

My exercise says to display employee names who were hired on sunday in the month of October

```
select ename,hiredate    from emp   where
to_char(hiredate,'MON')='OCTOBER' AND to_char(hiredate,'DAY')='SUNDAY'
```

Also

> Display all the employess who are hired in last quarter.

In oracle we cannot use qq so how to write a query for this?

Comment: In sql we can use qq in datepart. But there is no such method in oracle...right?

Comment: "*In oracle we cannot use qq so how to write a query for this?*" What does `qq` mean? If you mean **QUARTER**, then of course you could do it. But your requirement seems nothing to do with quarterly output. Also, with **day name**, beware that **TO_CHAR** is **NLS dependent**. If you do not specify the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, it would fail for people who are using a different `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MON date format is the abbreviated month name, in the current sesison's NLS date language. You can can compare the abbreviation with the short name, or the full month name:

```
to_char(hiredate,'MON')='OCT'
```

or

```
to_char(hiredate,'FMMONTH')='OCTOBER'
```

The ['FM' format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) stops it adding trailing spaces, which it does by default, up to the length of the longest possible value. If you don't do that you either have to pad your fixed value, or trim the result. (Note that for some languages the abbreviations need FM for comparison too as even their length can change; not in English as the MON and DY values are all 3 characters; but French month abbreviations, for example, can be 3 or 4 characters).

It's generally better to use month numbers for this though:

```
to_char(hiredate,'MM')='10'
```

That will get you October in any year; if you want this October you can include the year:

```
to_char(hiredate,'YYYYMM')='201510'
```

Or if you want the previous month of the current year you can use:

```
trunc(hire_date, 'MM') = add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1)
```

The same thing happens with the day; the DAY format pads to the longest day name by default, so you need:

```
to_char(hiredate,'DY')='SUN'
```

or

```
to_char(hiredate,'FMDAY')='SUNDAY'
```

You can use day numbers here but they are locale-dependent too. If you're gong to use names it's safer to specify the language:

```
to_char(hire_date,'FMDAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''')='SUNDAY'
```

Oracle does have [the Q date format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212), fixed to calendar months - so January-March is Q1. You may want financial quarters; or may want the previous three months; or something else.

Comment: Great answer. I stumbled over the padded names in the past and had totally forgotton about this. It's a real nuisance.

Answer (score 3):

You get the quarter with TO_CHAR('Q'). So get that quarter from sysdate and calculate the previous:

```
select ename,hiredate    
from emp   
where to_char(hiredate, 'q') =
  case to_char(sysdate, 'q') 
    when '1' then '4'
    when '2' then '1'
    when '3' then '2'
    when '4' then '3'
  end
and extract(year from hiredate) =
  case when to_char(sysdate, 'q') = '1' then 
    extract(year from sysdate) - 1
  else
    extract(year from sysdate)
  end;
```

As to Sunday in October, your query looks fine, but you rely on English settings for the database. Better use numbers where possible or specify the language used:

```
select ename, hiredate    
from emp   
where to_char(hiredate,'mm') = 10 
and to_char(hiredate, 'FMDAY', 'nls_date_language = american') = 'SUNDAY';
```

EDIT: I just read your question again and come to think: What does "last" quarter mean? The quarter before this, as I assumed, or quarter 4 of a year? That would be simply `where to_char(sysdate, 'q') = '4'`.

EDIT 2: Had to change 'DAY' to 'FMDAY'. See Alex Poole's answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

to know if the hiredate is in the last quarter you could check if the month is greater or equal to `10`

```
select ename,
       hiredate    
from   emp   
where  to_char(hiredate,'MM')>=10
```

For your other question, as statet [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php), `MON` return an abbreviated name of month. This causes that `OCTOBER` wont be the output of `MON`. You are either out for `MONTH` in your `to_char`, or you would want to compare it to `OCT` instead. As an alternative you could probably do it like this. If so keep @ThrostenKettner´s comment in mind.

```
select ename,
       hiredate 
from   emp   
where  to_char(hiredate,'MM')=10 
and    to_char(hiredate,'D')=1
```

Comment: Thanks and for displaying employee name who were hired on Sunday of October Month?

Comment: select ename,hiredate 
  from emp
  where to_char(hiredate,'MON')='OCT' AND to_char(hiredate,'DAY')='SUNDAY'                                                           Thanks :)

Comment: Be careful with TO_CHAR(something, 'D'). The value you get depends on the NLS_TERRITORY, so your query isn't guaranteed to work. (I consider it a flaw that you cannot specify the territory in TO_CHAR so as to get a relyable response on 'D'.)

Answer (score 0):

this is one type of logic to solve this question

please check if you want to use full thanks

SELECT ee.*,to_char(ee.hiredate,'Q') Quarter
FROM EMPLOYEES ee
WHERE  TO_CHAR(ee.HIREDATE,'DAY')   IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(dd.HIREDATE,'MON'),'DAY')
FROM EMPLOYEES dd)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?